# nav-tabs dentro de otro nav-tabs

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy tratando de crear un nav-tabs dentro de otro nav-tabs
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando intento cambiar de pagina en en segundo nav-tab este no cambia, solo se dejan de ver los datos de la page1 y abajo inmediatamente se muestran los de la page2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso solo se muestran las letras de la page 3 hasta abajo

quisiera saber si alguien sabe como arreglar este error, estoy usando bootstrap 4 y este es de la manera en que lo estoy realizando

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Product Categories</h2>
    <br>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Friction Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Clutches</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Safety</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Production</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Maintenance</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Shear Brake</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Press Controls</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page1">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page2">Page 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page3">Page 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="page1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <p>lkjasdhfalsdf</p>
        </div>

        <div id="page2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <p>shbflaksjdflk</p>
        </div>

        <div id="page3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <p>wertwertgfsd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

se que en los nombres de los nav se repiten varias veces, pero aun asi no se desaparecen los nav-tabs de page1 page2 y page3

Answer (score 1):

Te falto incluir el contenedor `tab-content` a los elementos div que difiniste para el contenido de cada page x.

Lo ajuste para el primer tab:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Product Categories</h2>
<br>
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Friction Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Clutches</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Safety</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Production</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Shear Brake</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="font-size: 12px;" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Press Controls</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<br>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page1">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page2">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page3">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="page1" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>lkjasdhfalsdf</p>
                </div>

                <div id="page2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>shbflaksjdflk</p>
                </div>

                <div id="page3" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>wertwertgfsd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/17s31qyz/1/)

En este [ENLACE](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs) esta el marcado de bootstrap que te puede ayudar a solucionar el problema también

Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Mariano , ahí coloque el código para la respuesta! De todas maneras, no entiendo los votos negativos ya que a pesar de que la respuesta original no fue la adecuada, soluciona el problema. Saludos